# Erroneous click event firing on form button when pressing Enter in input

Tags: javascript, input, click, enter

Erroneous click event firing on form button when pressing Enter in input

Somewhy, pressing Enter key while having focus on any of the form's inputs causes click event on first of the buttons to fire.

I understand that pressing Enter causes form submission, but why is it bound to click event on the button as well?

Works that way in FF and Chrome, didn't test other browsers.

Here is sample code using jQuery (I didn't try without it):

```html
<form>
  <input>
  <div>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $('body').on('keydown', 'input', function() {
    console.log('Keydown on input');
  });

  $('body').on('click', 'button', function() {
    console.log('Click on ' + $(this).text());
    return false; // to prevent page reloading caused by form submission
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Add `type=button` to your `<button>` tags. They're "submit" buttons by default, so that's where the click is coming from.

Comment: and preventDefault in the form's submit event

Comment: @Pointy yes, I'm aware about the workarounds. 
What remains unclear to me is why click on the button is fired on form submission at all. I didn't hear anything about it before and I'm in web technologies for 10 years already.

Comment: Is such behaviour explicitly described in any standards or some other documents?

Comment: @1234ru http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#form-submission-0 section 4.10.22.2 "Implicit Submission"

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for the reference, it is right on.